# Listviewitem Binding to a model type's static field in WPF?

Tags: c#, xaml

I'm wondering whether I have a way to bind listviewitem to static field of a Item model of `Listview`.

following pseudo-code is my condition.

```cs
model 
{
 public string name {get; set;}
 public string age {get; set;}
 public static ObservableCollection<string> recommended_schoolNames {get; set;}
 public string schoolName {get; set;}
}
```

and then, in xaml, I set property like this.

```xml
`ListView` ItemSources = ObservableCollection<model> data;

<DataTempate>  
`ListviewItem1` <TextBox Text={Binding age}>  //works good
`ListviewItem2` <TextBox Text={Binding name}>  // works good

then, I need to show combo box to user can select school from recommended_schoolNames.  

<ComboBox .... ItemsSource={Binding recommended_schoolName}>.
</DataTemplate>
```

I'm fine If you suggest another solution to solve this problem.
I considered move static `observablecollection<string>` from model to view model's `ObservableCollection<string>`, but failed to set Item source of combo box in Listview Itemtemplate reference Viewmodel properties.

I'm sorry for my poor English skills. thank you for reading this.

### Added

as Christoper suggest, I tried to move static ObservableCollection from model class to ObservableCollection of viewModel.

but failed.. following is my source.

```cs
viewmodel{
        public ObservavbleCollection <model> myModel {get; set;}
        public ObservableCollection<string> nnames { get; set; }
}
```

```xml
 <ListView
            x:Name="VariableListView"
            Grid.Row="2"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
            HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
            Background="Transparent"
            ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource ListViewItemStyle}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding variableModels}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding selectedItem}"
            SelectionMode="Extended"
            Style="{DynamicResource VariableListViewStyle}">

            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                     <ComboBox
                                x:Name="DefaultValueCombobox"
                                Grid.Column="2"
                                Width="147"
                                Height="24"
                                Margin="12,0,0,0"
                                DataContext="{Binding Source={x:Reference Name=variableUserControl}, Path=DataContext}"
                                Foreground="#FFEAEAEA"
                                ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource gridViewComboBoxItemStyle}"
                                ItemsSource="{Binding nnames}"
                                SelectedItem="{Binding DefaultValue}"
                                Style="{DynamicResource VariableComboBoxStyle}" />
```

Comment: Why is that thing static, and is there any way to avoid it? Statics in are globals and thus generally a bad idea.

Comment: @Christopher Okay, I need to show `recommended_schoolnames` all same to Listview item. if you suggest to avoid static field, then I need to control it in view model...

Comment: @Christopher thank you I solved with without using static

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved with setting Control datacontext.

```cs
<ComboBox
                                x:Name="DefaultValueCombobox"
                                Grid.Column="2"
                                Width="147"
                                Height="24"
                                Margin="12,0,0,0"
                                DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext}"
                                Foreground="#FFEAEAEA"
                                ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource gridViewComboBoxItemStyle}"
                                ItemsSource="{Binding nnnames}"
                                SelectedItem="{Binding DefaultValue}"
                                Style="{DynamicResource VariableComboBoxStyle}" />
```

I tried before this, but failed. I found the reason. 
I didn't allocate `ObservableCollection<string>` at that time. -_-..
I didn't notice output console of visual studio...

## ADD

I finished my job as follow. I bind data with using `RelativeSource`.

```cs
<ComboBox
                                x:Name="DefaultValueCombobox"
                                Grid.Column="2"
                                Width="147"
                                Height="24"
                                Margin="12,0,0,0"
                                Foreground="#FFEAEAEA"
                                ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource gridViewComboBoxItemStyle}"
                                ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.nnnames, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
                                SelectedItem="{Binding DefaultValue}"
                                Style="{DynamicResource VariableComboBoxStyle}" />
```